# Existe problemas em declarar muitas funções noexcept?

Tags: c++, exceção, c++14, c++17

Eu vejo muitos códigos em C++14/C++17 em que o programador tem certeza que a função vai lançar exceção, mas não informa isso pro compilador, talvez porque pode ocasionar algum problema ao informar muitas funções como noexcept? Existe algum problema em definir muitas funções como noexcept? Se sim, quais?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`noexcept` é uma ferramenta com um propósito específico de permitir certas otimizações, que não seriam possíveis caso exceções tivessem de serem levadas em conta.
A primeira otimização que vem em minha cabeça agora é o `std::vector` mover seus elementos caso seus move constructors forem `noexcept`.

Marcar toda função com `noexcept` provavelmente não é uma boa ideia. O uso excessivo e sem propósito de uma ferramenta não traz benefícios, pelo contrário. O especificador `noexcept` funciona como um contrato: adiciona-a em funções que tem-se absoluta certeza de que não irá lançar (lê-se `throw`) uma exceção, e que nunca será trocada para possivelmente lançáveis, ou se definitivamente deseja-se que `std::terminate` seja chamado caso uma exceção ocorra.

Mas isso não significa adicionar `noexcept` em toda e qualquer função arbitrariamente.

Entretanto, é possível desativar exceções em C++ nos compiladores [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_exceptions.html#intro.using.exception.no), [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-fexceptions) e [MSVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5.aspx), renderizando o uso de `noexcept` redundante. É necessário, todavia, recompilar a biblioteca padrão para usá-la sem exceções, ou simplesmente abandoná-la, porque ela é lotada de `throw`s.